# group by factor and return second lowest value of other column

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to group this data frame by the values in `zipcode` column, and return in another (called rate) column the `second lowest` rate or the `lowest` rate or the `max` rate.

**For example, from this df:**

```
zipcode state   county_code name    rate_area_x plan_id metal_level rate    rate_area_y
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  52161YL6358432  Silver  245.82  6
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  01100AO4222848  Silver  271.77  5
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  24848KC5063721  Silver  264.84  1
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  89885YK0256118  Silver  269.11  8
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  65392ON5819785  Silver  305.02  12
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  52161YL6358432  Silver  245.82  6
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  01100AO4222848  Silver  271.77  5
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  24848KC5063721  Silver  264.84  1
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  89885YK0256118  Silver  269.11  8
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  65392ON5819785  Silver  305.02  12
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  90884WN5801293  Silver  323.25  2
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  79113BU1788705  Silver  344.81  7
```

I'd expect:

```
zipcode rate
36749   245.82
30165   245.82
```

**In R I'd do this to get the min value for each zipcode group:**

```
grouped_df <- df %>%
              group_by(zipcode) %>%
              summarise(rate = min(rate))
```

**But how to get the second lowest rate value using Python's Pandas?**

Comment: "245.82" is the lowest, not the second lowest value. I think you need `df.sort_values('rate').groupby('zipcode').nth(1)` but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit**: I give you both smallest and 2nd smallest for you using in general case. However, as @WenYoBen mentioned in the comment you probably only want the 2nd lowest. If that is the case, you just need to chain `reset_index`, `drop`, and `drop_duplicates` to get smallest or 2nd smallest as follows:

**Get smallest**:

```
df.groupby('zipcode').rate.nsmallest(2).reset_index().drop('level_1',1) \
  .drop_duplicates(subset=['zipcode'])

Out[2108]:
       zipcode    rate
    0    30165  245.82
    2    36749  245.82
```

---

**Get 2nd smallest**:

```
df.groupby('zipcode').rate.nsmallest(2).reset_index().drop('level_1',1) \
  .drop_duplicates(subset=['zipcode'], keep='last')

Out[2109]:
   zipcode    rate
1    30165  264.84
3    36749  264.84
```

---

**Original**:

`groupby.nsmallest` will give you smallest and 2nd smallest of each group

```
df.groupby('zipcode').rate.nsmallest(2)

Out[2083]:
zipcode
30165    5    245.82
         7    264.84
36749    0    245.82
         2    264.84
Name: rate, dtype: float64
```

Comment: You sure this is return the second lowest value ?

Comment: doc describes `Return the smallest n elements`. Passing `n=2` supposedly returns `smallest` and `2nd smallest`.  Link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nsmallest.html#pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nsmallest. Do I misunderstand its functionality?

Comment: from what I understanding he only need the 2nd lowest not 1st and 2nd

Comment: @WeNYoBen: I added the code to give separate lowest and 2nd lowest values. Is it what you mean?

Comment: Look better now :-)

Answer (score 1):

To get the results into a `Dataframe` you can use the `group_by` method with `to_frame`. Note, to get the nth lowest (and not the [:nth] lowest) sort the `df` and select the `n` you require.

```
import pandas as pd

data="""zipcode state   county_code name    rate_area_x plan_id metal_level rate    rate_area_y
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  52161YL6358432  Silver  245.82  6
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  01100AO4222848  Silver  271.77  5
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  24848KC5063721  Silver  264.84  1
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  89885YK0256118  Silver  269.11  8
36749   AL  1001    Autauga 11  65392ON5819785  Silver  305.02  12
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  52161YL6358432  Silver  245.82  6
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  01100AO4222848  Silver  271.77  5
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  24848KC5063721  Silver  264.84  1
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  89885YK0256118  Silver  269.11  8
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  65392ON5819785  Silver  305.02  12
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  90884WN5801293  Silver  323.25  2
30165   AL  1019    Cherokee    13  79113BU1788705  Silver  344.81  7"""

# create dataframe
n_columns = 9
data = [data.split()[x:x+n_columns] for x in range(0, len(data.split()), n_columns)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0]).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')

# ensure the dataframe is sorted
df = df.sort_values(['zipcode','rate'])

min_df = df.groupby('zipcode').rate.min().to_frame(name = 'rate').reset_index()

max_df = df.groupby('zipcode').rate.max().to_frame(name = 'rate').reset_index()

second_lowest_df = df.groupby('zipcode').rate.nth(1).to_frame(name = 'rate').reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

`sort` then `groupby` + `nth`. This gives you the flexibility to choose any arbitrarily ranked values (by passing a list). Drop duplicates if you don't want to double-count the same value.

```
df.sort_values(['rate']).groupby('zipcode').rate.nth([1])
#zipcode
#30165    264.84
#36749    264.84
#Name: rate, dtype: float64
```

If you want the smallest, fourth smallest and largest values:

```
df.sort_values(['rate']).groupby('zipcode').rate.nth([0, 3, -1])
#zipcode
#30165    245.82
#30165    271.77
#30165    344.81
#36749    245.82
#36749    271.77
#36749    305.02
#Name: rate, dtype: float64
```

Out of bounds selections are ignored in groups where they do not exist:

```
df.sort_values(['rate']).groupby('zipcode').rate.nth(5)
#zipcode
#30165    323.25
#Name: rate, dtype: float64
```

Redundant selectors are not double counted (both 6 and -1 refer to the max element in 30165)

```
df.sort_values(['rate']).groupby('zipcode').rate.nth([6, 6, -1])
#zipcode
#30165    344.81
#36749    305.02
#Name: rate, dtype: float64
```